# How to avoid memory leak from Observable subscriprions wihtin a Service in Angular?

Tags: angular, service, memory-leaks, observable, subscription

I am used to unsubscribing from Ovservable subscriptions on the ngOnDestroy Hook when I subscribe to an observable within a component. But the problem is when I subscribe from within a Service where there is no such thing as "On Destroy" since the service lives as long as the app is running.

How Do I avoid the memory leak in this case?

Comment: Hi, good question you could create a global variable in the service to store the subscription and a function to unsubscribe, which is launched by the component that uses the service from ngOnDestroy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs for [OnDestroy](https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy), services can implement OnDestroy.

> A lifecycle hook that is called when a directive, pipe, **or service** is destroyed. Use for any custom cleanup that needs to occur when the instance is destroyed.

Like components, this is typically where you would unsubscribe from observables.